# Importing script from local package during setuptools CustomInstall

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I have the following setup:

```
`- MyLibrary
  `- pyproject.toml
  `- setup.cfg
  `- setup.py
  `- Package1
    `- ...
  `- Package2
    `- ...
  `- CodeGen
    `- __init__.py
    `- Generate.py
```

and I need the install script to run a `generate()` function from `CodeGen.Generate` to include some extra code in the distribution.

I have tried the following:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.install import install

from .CodeGen import generate

class CustomInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        generate()

setup(
    cmdclass={"install": CustomInstall},
    name="MyLibrary",
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

With setuptools as my build backend. But running `pip install .` fails with the following error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

on the line `from .CodeGen import generate`.

How can I make it so that the `CodeGen` script is importable in my `setup.py`? Note that it depends on some package dependencies, which are listed in the `[build-system]` `requires` field of my `pyproject.toml`.

Alternatively, how would I achieve this differently?

Comment: In principle `from CodeGen import generate`, without leading dot `.`, as absolute import, not sure why you would want a relative import here. -- I am not 100% sure, but I think `pip install...` does not actually go through the `install` command of the `setup.py`. I think maybe you should override the `build_py` command instead, I do not remember exactly.

Comment: Inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71137790

Comment: Ah yeah I should have mentioned, I also tried `from CodeGen import generator`, and it fails instead with something along the lines of "no such package/module".

Comment: "*Something along the lines*"? Knowing the exact error message and the exact project structure are essential to finding the issue. -- So, is it `generate` or `generator`? Is it a function that is placed in `CodeGen/__init__.py` or what is it and in which file is it defined? -- I recreated what I "**think**" your project structure is (but I am not sure), and `from CodeGen import generate` works perfectly fine for me, as expected, no surprise.